# How to parse the date portion of a datetime string in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, string, date, datetime

I have this datetime string

`Tue, 20 Oct 2015 17:14:47 +0200`

I need to return the date portion from this. In other words, get `date`, `month` and `year` from it.

Currently I've done:

```
pub_date = new Date("Tue, 20 Oct 2015 17:14:47 +0200")
day      = pub_date.getDate()
month    = pub_date.getMonth()
year     = pub_date.getYear()
```

Only the `day` gets returned correctly. `month` and `year` return the wrong results. What would be more correct?

Comment: What are the incorrect results you are seeing?

Comment: when in doubt ..read the manual  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be `pub_date.getFullYear()`. `getYear()` has been deprecated.

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_getfullyear.asp

Also, the month returns a number from 0 to 11. You should create a months array and access the result of `getMonth`.

```
var months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", 
              "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
month = months[pub_date.getMonth()];
```

Or if you're using angular, you can use the built-in date filter

```
{{ date | format: 'MMMM' }}
```

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date

Comment: Thanks, that makes everything clear now :) I'll accept your answer in 10 minutes

Comment: indexing is off for `month` ... your array is also zero based

Comment: Just caught that. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

According to the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date):

> **Date.prototype.getMonth()**
>
> Returns the month (0-11) in the specified date according to local time.
>
> **Date.prototype.getFullYear()**
>
> Returns the year (4 digits for 4-digit years) of the specified date according to local time.

So you'd want:

```
pub_date = new Date("Tue, 20 Oct 2015 17:14:47 +0200")
day      = pub_date.getDate()
month    = pub_date.getMonth() + 1
year     = pub_date.getFullYear()
```

Answer (score 1):

What results do you expect exactly ?
.getMonth() should return you 9, which is correct because monthes are numbered 0 to 11.

Use .getFullYear() instead of getYear(), that should return you 2015.